# Metadata file not found error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, metadata

I am dealing with a really huge work such that we have a solution and there are about 100-120 projects under it. Once I was trying to launch it but it took extra long I had to cancel it. Now a number of dll files under bin folder are lost, and most of those files were created by fellow projects under the solution. 
Now I cannot rebuild/build.

Till now:
-have cleaned and tried to rebuild the solutions and project folders(each folder, is directly under solution contains like 5-6 projects) one by one. I also tried rebuilding projects one by one but it took too long and was useless.

-cleaned the solution, restarted visual studio(even the computer itself), but did not worked.

-cleared the Temporary ASP.NET Files under C:\Windows\microsoft\\ TEmp... and failed to relaunch again.

-Also tried to manually add missing references to projects but since there are over 100 projects it is not useful and will not work.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to delete the current solution and get it back from TFS and it resolved our problem.

Answer (score 0):

try everything...(in order of a little to a lot of time wasted)

1. Do you have bad code? Fix that first.
2. Clean Solution & Restart Visual Studio
3. Remove / Add References
4. Check your build order w/ larger projects and verify
5. Manually rebuild sub-projects
6. Manually copy dlls between projects into associated bin folders
7. Go get some coffee, play some pinball and come back tomorrow...you may think of something else in the meanwhile.

Comment: I am at step 7. I mentioned above that I tried all of them(saw them under a similar topic.)

Answer (score 0):

I've been there before, it is a painful process.  After you do what Vignesh told you, or while you do that, you can also use Dependency Walker to help figure out which dependencies are missing.  This tool from the old days is still available for free and has helped a poor soul many times over.  The main download page is dependencywalker dot com.

An additional tool to use is CheckAsm.  Simplified, CheckAsm is a dependency walker for .NET.
It shows all .NET assembly references for any of your .NET assemblies.  This tool is located at amberfish dot net.  (They have an evaluation version which is free.)

I wish you well.

Comment: Thanks a lot but those tools only give ability to watch over assembly files one by one, in case of >100 projects it is not possible to watch and figure out dependencies.